# Replacing leaking AC condenser and reciever dryer after 6 years of no refrigerant at all. Do I replace all PAG oil?

Tags: ac, corolla, condenser

I'm in a unique enough situation that I don't think I can trust my research completely. My AC condenser in my 2000 Corolla was dented 6 years ago and consequently all the refrigerant leaked out slowly. I lived in Colorado Springs so I didn't need to fix it. I moved to a hot and humid climate so I've bought everything to fix it before summer. I evacuated the system with the old condenser still in and it held the vacuum overnight without budging, indicating a very slow leak. I intend to only replace the dryer and condenser, but I'm worried about the compressor running dry if I don't add the pag oil directly to the compressor. Will all of the old PAG 46 oil have slowly evaporated from the system? Will adding the correct amount of PAG 46 oil directly to the dryer and condesner be enough? Or do I need to add some to the compressor directly? I have a new bottle of PAG 46 in liquid form, not a pressurized can. Basically, I'm not sure If I need to add the entire system capacity of PAG oil or just enough for the parts I'm replacing. If anyone could help me answer these questions I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: If the system "held vacuum overnight," how do you conclude that it has "a very slow leak?"

Comment: Because the pressure on the high and low line was at zero when I connected the manifolds. Also, the original condenser was bent in a car accident and my ac stopped working after that. Those two facts indicate to me that a slowly leaking system is likely the problem. I know that some leaking systems will take 2 weeks to lose enough refrigerant to stop working, so holding a vacuum overnight doesn't indicate a completely solid system if I know the refrigerant was lost.

Comment: Because you lost pressure probably means that you have a small leak, but not necessarily. I've seen when a condenser gets hit it will jolt a connection with an O ring hard enough to loose its seal through the O ring and then return to seal. If it was me and I was doing the work myself, I would put the proper amount of oil in when changing your parts. Make sure to hold a vacuum for more than an hour. Then fill. The oil does travel through the system.

Comment: ***Correction to my above comment*** I had a faulty set of manifolds. With good manifolds, the system cannot hold a vacuum at all with the original condenser. I can hear it hissing as it draws air through the small crack in the dent.

Comment: Thanks Jupiter, that helps. After using working manifolds, I noticed a white mist coming from the vacuum. I wonder if this is the old oil, water or both. There was nothing coming from the vacuum yesterday when only the hoses were in vacuum.

Comment: Thinking on this again, I do believe A.C. systems can be flushed. If done professionally, they would know how much oil it would need. After sitting that many years exposed, it might be a good idea to check out that option.